# PDFBox 2.0: how to detect bold text here

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I know there many ways to do bold text in PDF, most common are "bold" keywords in TextPosition.getFont(). However, in attached document I was not able to find why that bold text is actually bold:

capture of pdf

[image]

Visually it looks like each character is duplicated twice, however, I don't see that in TextStripper.writeString
Is there anything else can make text bold?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Your file uses `text rendering mode` 2 (fill and stroke). This simulates bold.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I think you can get the current mode by calling `getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode()`.

Comment: This is exactly the case, thank you very much. Just a quick question, how did you find it without trying? is there any way except debugging pdf content stream in PDFBox sources?

Comment: I used PDFDebugger. Mode 2 was a guess because I saw only one font in the page resources. Then I looked for "Tr" in the content stream. Then I searched the API how to get the current text rendering mode.

Comment: @DmitryK Does Tilman's answer sufficiently answer your question? Or are there still open issues? I ask because you did not mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @mkl sorry, accepted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file uses [text rendering mode](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=254) 2 (fill and stroke, aka `RenderingMode.FILL_STROKE`). This simulates bold. You can get the current mode by calling `getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode()` in a class that extends the stripper.

Comment: One should not check the text rendering mode alone, always check it in combination with the fill and stroke colors: If both colors are (approximately) the same, rendering mode 2 indeed is a poor-man's-bold. But if the fill color is similar to the background color, this is a poor-man's-outline variant. And if instead the stroke color is similar to the background color, rendering mode 2 can actually be a poor-man's-*light* variant. And if both colors differ from each other and from the background, this is a fun font... ;)